# pros and cons of a contact form without captcha tool

Tags: php, security, captcha, contact-form

I am providing a simple php contact form on my webserver. The form include fields for name, email, message and one hidden 'do-not-enter-anything'. If the 'do-not-enter-anything' field has some value after user input, the server will not send any message. I do not use a captcha tool. Which problems could occur without the use of captcha? I am not afraid of getting randomly spam messages. Is it possible to knock out the server with the contact form and a script (on an easier way)? Are there other disadvantages?

Comment: The technique you describe is called a "honeypot". Also, don't underestimate the power of bots. What is the need for a contact form if you receive 100+ spam messages daily by just 1 bot?

Comment: Also, your question is too broad and is asking for opinion based responses.

Comment: Pro - Easier for the user to use. Con - Bots might get pass it.

Comment: Had once a registration form without captcha. Server got knocked down, but I am also running several other forms with your mentioned 'do-not-enter-anything' field without any issue since years. Occasionally I get spam. Btw. captchas can be bypassed as well.